# $\ell_{p}$ space closed to addition

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to show that $\ell_{p}$
  is a vector space for any $1\leqslant p<\infty$
 . So given two infinite series $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
  and $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
  such such that ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}}$
  and ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|y_{n}\right|^{p}}$
  converge and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$
  I want to show that $$\left[\alpha\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}+\beta\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}\right]\in\ell_{p}$$
 To do that I need to show that $${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\alpha x_{n}+\beta y_{n}\right|^{p}}<\infty$$
 For some reason I'm finding this quite hard, I've been unsuccesful in bounding this sum from above by the two convergent series I started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to prove it's a subspace of a bigger vector space, for which we know it's already one. For example, the space of real sequences. (otherwise, we have to check all the axioms).

**Hint:** use and show the inequality $(a+b)^p\leqslant 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$ for non-negative $a$ and $b$.

Comment: At first I wasn't sure how to justify that inequality but after the pointer from Learner I recalled that $x^p$ is convex over the positive reals and that sorted it all out.

Thanks for both your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the proof of the [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) (the sequence case).